# Wordpress permissions Ubuntu

Tags: wordpress

While trying to upload a header image to Wordpress theme twenty eleven I get this error:

```
Unable to create directory /srv/www/wp-uploads/i3e.ndu.edu.lb/2012/11.
Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

Even though the server is up and running and the website is accessible.
I've messed it up more than once so I need the exact steps.

Comment: **Wordpress - Folder permission on LINUX UBUNTU** http://wordpress.org/support/topic/folder-permission-on-linux-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue after installing wordpress on a fresh Ubuntu Amazon AMI. The issue for me was that `/src/www` was not group permissioned `www-data`, it was set to `root/root` with `750` permissions. Update `www` to `www-data` group: `chgrp www-data www`.